# How to use res.sendFile and res.json together

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, response

When home page loads, a call is done to `/` , and simultaneously an AJAX call is also being done to `/courses`.

A **JSON** response from `/courses` is being used in the **HTML** returned by `/` call.

But an error as shown below is occuring in this implementation.
`Error:Cannot set headers after they are sent`.

I guess this is due to the simultaneous call to `/` and and AJAX call to `/courses`.

What is the solution for this, if the error is due to what i think?

Please ask, if more code is required.
The necessary code is being shown below:

**NodeJS snippet**

```
var express        = require('express');
var router         = express.Router();
var db1  = require('../models/courseDetails.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

router.get('/courses',function(req,res){
    db1.find({},function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log("I am in trouble from NODEJS")
    }else{
        console.log("coming back with the DATA for all courses:");
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log("Have complete data...................................");
        res.json(data);
    }

    })
    res.json(data)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**FACTORY snippet**(where AJAX call is being initiated)

```
.factory('courses',function($http){
return{
    list:function(callback){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/courses'  

        })
        .success(callback)
        .error(function(error){
            console.log('I am in error of AJAX,allCourses')
        })

    }
})
```

Comment: You are doing `res.json` twice in the response to `/courses`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is an Express error that happens when your code is setting headers on the response object after the response has finished. In your case you are calling `res.json()` which will set the `Content-Type` header, and you are calling this twice in your `/courses` endpoint. This is happening after your `if/else` block, where you are calling `res.json()` again.

Refactor your code to something like this:

```
router.get('/courses',function(req,res){
    db1.find({},function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log("I am in trouble from NODEJS")
            res.status(500).json({
                message : 'Error getting courses'
            });
        } else {
            console.log("coming back with the DATA for all courses:");
            console.log(data[0]);
            console.log("Have complete data...................................");
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I added some error handling in the case of an error coming from your database query with a 500 status code, and a 200 OK with all the json data if the database query is successful.